# AsyncTask or AsyncTaskLoader for long lived data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I need to download data that need to survive beyond the life cycle of the activity that loaded said data. Right now I have a LocalData class. As an inner class of my LocalData, I am using an AsyncTask to fetch data from a remote server. My LocalData class keeps the data in memory (i.e. a field), so that if the activity is later re-opened then the same data is available -- that way I don't make unnecessary calls to the server. A simple skeleton of the class is

```
class LocalData{
  private List<MyPojo> myData;

  public void fetchData(String query){
    //...
    //here I start asynctask that loads data into myData
    //I have call backs to notify activity, say I use Observer-Observable or whatever
  }

  public List<MyPojo> getData(){
    return myData;
  }
}
```

I am wondering whether I should continue to use AsyncTask or switch to AsyncTaskLoader. Please include some explanation, otherwise I won't learn anything from your answer. Thanks.

I don't suppose this is important, but the data is for an adapter.

Comment: instead of ansync task use threads in a service, service runs independent of an activity or app lifecycle, and if your data is big, you can persist it on storage in that same thread and fetch back when the app or activity is being called upon, that's pretty easy, with this you can fall on your own logic and implement it better, after all async task creates a new `Thread` calls `Looper` to run the onPostexecute and its ui methods on the main `thread`.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is cache it to disk: you can use the async task, but once you obtain the data, write it to the app's cache directory. Then next time, you can check if the cache exists, and if so fetch it from disk before requesting from the server. You can, for instance, delete the cache each time the app starts to keep it fresh (or use a combination of an expiration date). Since it doesn't seem like the data changes much, an async task loader might be overkill.

--Async versus Loader--

So async tasks are for short lived tasks, for instance getting a simple amount of data from a server, or processing a bitmap, or something of that sort. Problems with async tasks is you can lose reference to them if your activity is scraped, even though you still want the result to persist. Ways around this are: disk cache the results in your async task (since its on disk, you can find it there next time you come back) instead of returning in `onPostExecute`; set the async task to talk to a retained non-ui fragment; set the async task to serve up to an application scoped singleton.

Note you can always achieve calling back to the UI thread from any background thread by using `Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()); h.post(new Runnable() { /* run * };);`.

Loaders are like async tasks but *specialized to be integrated with the UI*: hence instead of `onPostExecute` you have `onLoadFinished`. For instance, I made an app for searching and browsing quotes: I had a content provider of all the quotes (denormalized) so the user could browse by tag, author, subject, etc. Using a cursor loader, I was easily able to update the UI to reflect what the user was searching for (or if they had changed a tag) since the cursor loader would handle reloading the data in the background and updating the UI provided I implemented the callbacks correctly: unlike an async task, I didn't have to manage the loader if the activity went through a configuration change, if they user decided to switch browsing criteria (switch fragments), or manage passing around the cursor(s) myself, just implement the three loader callbacks in each fragment.

As far as analogies go, you might say where an async task is like a macro or alias in your shell, a loader would be like a script.

That was quick and rough, but hopefully helps.

Comment: Caching to disk may be a bit too strong in my case. I simply don't want to query my server for the same exact call. So imagine a search engine where a user searches for "apple". If they then leave that activity and returns later and query for "apple" I want to server the data I already have. But if instead they search for "orange", then I can search again. This example is an add-on to the original question; so all the original contexts apply.

Comment: So you'll want to use a memory cache but you'll have to store it in, for instance, your application instance if you want it to persist beyond the life-cycle of a single activity. Usually that's done with a singleton: as an alternative, you might as well write it to disk since it is fast and fairly easy to do (if its json or whatever, just write the string, nothing could be simpler). You can use the search terms as your cache key--either as the file name on disk or in a hashmap in the application singleton. Again, loaders are not for what you want to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to know that:

AsyncTaskLoader use when you don't have to write code that handles activity configuration changes.

- limitations you can't change fragments in onLoadFinished.

When you need UI changes after data is loaded you use AsyncTask(especially fragments).

So.... if you need UI changes use AsyncTask,if you dont use AsyncTaskLoader.

Comment: I read that same stuff in the docs and didn't understand it then and don't understand it now. Which is why I ask my question.